# HTML inside PHP file not loading external CSS file

Tags: php, html, css

I haven't coded for a long time and my skills are basic.
I got a php file. It's a section file from a wordpress theme i am customizing.

My problem is. Made the code to link to an external css file to customize the social media icons, but it's not loading the CSS!

### Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:\xampp\htdocs\alfasteel.pt\wp-content\themes\onetone\css\socialmedia.css" />
 </head>
 <body>


          <div class="footer-social-icons">
    <h4 class="_14">Follow us on</h4>
    <ul class="social-icons">
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Here's the whole file code in case you need it:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:\xampp\htdocs\alfasteel.pt\wp-content\themes\onetone\css\socialmedia.css" />
 </head>
 <body>


<?php
 global $onetone_animated, $onetone_section_id, $allowedposttags;   
 $i                   = $onetone_section_id ;
 $section_title       = onetone_option( 'section_title_'.$i );
 $section_menu        = onetone_option( 'menu_title_'.$i );
 $section_content     = onetone_option( 'section_content_'.$i );
 $content_model       = onetone_option( 'section_content_model_'.$i);
 $section_subtitle    = onetone_option( 'section_subtitle_'.$i );
 $left_content        = onetone_option( 'section_left_content_'.$i );
 $right_content       = onetone_option( 'section_right_content_'.$i );

 if( !isset($section_content) || $section_content=="" ) 
    $section_content = onetone_option( 'sction_content_'.$i );


        if( $content_model == '0' || $content_model == ''  ):
        ?>

         <?php if( $section_title != '' || (function_exists('is_customize_preview') && is_customize_preview()) ):?>
       <?php  
           $section_title_class = '';
           if( $section_subtitle == '' && !(function_exists('is_customize_preview') && is_customize_preview()))
           $section_title_class = 'no-subtitle';
        ?>
       <h2 class="section-title <?php echo esc_attr($section_title_class); ?> <?php echo 'section_title_'.$i;?>"><?php echo wp_kses($section_title, $allowedposttags);?></h2>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if( $section_subtitle != '' || (function_exists('is_customize_preview') && is_customize_preview()) ):?>
        <div class="section-subtitle <?php echo 'section_subtitle_'.$i;?>"><?php echo do_shortcode(wp_kses($section_subtitle, $allowedposttags));?></div>
         <?php endif;?>
         <div class="home-section-content">

          <div class="footer-social-icons">
    <h4 class="_14">Follow us on</h4>
    <ul class="social-icons">
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>



         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8"><div class="<?php echo $onetone_animated;?> <?php echo 'section_left_content_'.$i;?>" data-animationduration="0.9" data-animationtype="fadeInLeft" data-imageanimation="no"><?php echo do_shortcode($left_content);?></div></div>
         <div class="col-md-4"><div class="<?php echo $onetone_animated;?> <?php echo 'section_right_content_'.$i;?>" data-animationduration="0.9" data-animationtype="fadeInRight" data-imageanimation="no"><?php echo do_shortcode($right_content);?></div></div>
         </div>
          </div>
           <?php
        else:
        ?>
        <?php if( $section_title != '' || (function_exists('is_customize_preview') && is_customize_preview()) ):?>
        <div class="section-title <?php echo 'section_title_'.$i;?>"><?php echo esc_attr($section_title);?></div>
        <?php endif;?>

            <div class="home-section-content <?php echo 'section_content_'.$i;?>">
            <?php 
            if(function_exists('Form_maker_fornt_end_main'))
             {
                 $section_content = Form_maker_fornt_end_main($section_content);
              }
             echo do_shortcode(wp_kses($section_content, $allowedposttags));
            ?>
            </div>
              <?php 
        endif;
        ?>      

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a path on your hard drive. that won't work.

Comment: It is a stylesheet reference, you need to load .css file. You are trying to attach .php. As others have said your path is also incorrect.

Comment: @DanielA.White

What do you mean i have a path on my hard drive?

Comment: @Klav 

Yes i changed to .css.

Comment: @Klav there is no issue referencing a *.php file as CSS as long as the PHP file sends the right headers. Headers is, usually, what determines behavior, not file postfixes

Answer (score 0):

Your files sit under the web server htdocs folder. You can access them over HTTP by specifying their URI.
change `href="D:\xampp\htdocs\alfasteel.pt\wp-content\themes\onetone\css\socialmedia.php"`
to
`href="http://localhost/alfasteel.pt/wp-content/themes/onetone/css/socialmedia.php"`

Comment: I can access the files in the browser both ways.

I did what you mentioned but icons as still not affected by css.

This is what i am trying to use: https://codepen.io/Deadlymuffin/pen/hGiqo/

Comment: show the css for the icons - that is  a different (but similar) problem of putting the right URI/path

Comment: also, try watching your page with developer tools/firebug etc, it might show you the problem right away,

Answer (score 0):

As @Itay Moav -Malimovka suggested

It was the path that wasn't the right way!

This works!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/alfasteel.pt/wp-content/themes/onetone/css/socialmedia.css" />
```

Thanks a lot for your help guys!